# Wrapping entities from Z3 C API

Tags: z3

I'm experimenting with enumeration sorts in Z3 as described in [How to use enumerated constants after calling of some tactic in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085232/how-to-use-enumerated-constants-after-calling-of-some-tactic-in-z3) and I noticed that I might have some misunderstanding on how to use C and C++ api properly. Let's consider the following example.

```
   context z3_cont;
   Z3_symbol e_names[2 ];
   Z3_func_decl e_consts[2];
   Z3_func_decl e_testers[2];

   e_names[0] = Z3_mk_string_symbol(z3_cont, "x1"); 
   e_names[1] = Z3_mk_string_symbol(z3_cont, "x2"); 
   Z3_symbol e_name = Z3_mk_string_symbol(z3_cont, "enum_type");  
   Z3_sort new_enum_sort = Z3_mk_enumeration_sort(z3_cont, e_name, 2, e_names, e_consts, e_testers);

   sort enum_sort = to_sort(z3_cont, new_enum_sort);
   expr e_const0(z3_cont), e_const1(z3_cont);

/* WORKS!
   func_decl a_decl = to_func_decl(z3_cont, e_consts[0]);
   func_decl b_decl = to_func_decl(z3_cont, e_consts[1]);
   e_const0 = a_decl(0, 0);
   e_const1 = b_decl(0, 0);   
*/
   // SEGFAULT when doing cout
   e_const0 = to_func_decl(z3_cont, e_consts[0])(0, 0);
   e_const1 = to_func_decl(z3_cont, e_consts[1])(0, 0);

   cout << e_const0 << " " << e_const1 << endl;
```

I expected the two variants of code to nicely wrap the C entity Z3_func_decl with a smart pointer so I can use with C++ api, however only the first variant seems to be correct. So my questions are

1. Is this a correct behavior that the second  way doesn't work? If so, how can I better understand the reasons of why it shouldn't?
2. What happens with unwrapped C entities, as for example Z3_symbol e_name - here I don't wrap it, I don't increment references.  So will the memory be managed properly? Is it safe to use it? when the object will be destroyed?
3. A minor question: I didn't see the to_symbol() function in C++ api. Is it just unnecessary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whenever we create a new Z3 AST, Z3 may garbage collect an AST `n` if the reference counter of `n` is 0. In the piece of code that works, we wrap `e_consts[0]` and `e_consts[1]` before we create any new AST. When we wrap them, the smart pointer will bump their reference counter. 
   This is why it works. In the piece of code that crashes, we wrap `e_consts[0]`, and then create `e_const0` before we wrap `e_consts[1]`. Thus, the AST referenced by `e_consts[1]` is deleted before we have the chance to create `e_const1`.

   BTW, in the next official release, we will have support for creating enumeration types in the C++ API: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/b2810592e6bb

   This change is already available in the nightly builds.
2. `Z3_symbol` is not a reference counted object. They are persistent, Z3 maintains a global table of all symbols created. We should view symbols as unique strings.
3. Note that we can use the class `symbol` and the constructor `symbol::symbol(context & c, Z3_symbol s)`. The functions `to_*` are used to wrap objects created using the C API with smart pointers. We usually have a function `to_A`, if there is a C API function that returns an `A` object, and there is not function/method equivalent in the C++.

Comment: thank you for a clear explanation. I updated the constant names in your reply according to my last edit for easier code understanding.

Comment: Is it safe enough to assume that Z3 won't garbage collect the still-not-reference-counted objects while I'll gradually be wrapping them (imagine I had 100 enum constants over there). As you said -- Z3 can garbage collect them whenever the reference counter is zero. Z3 is multi-threading library right, so I just thought what if GC happens to work in a separate thread and will collect the Z3_AST before I have any chance to wrap them even though I plan to and don't make any new AST :)

Comment: Yes, we can assume that Z3 will not garbage collect while we are gradually wrapping objects. Z3 will only garbage collect an AST if we invoke an API that allocates another AST. Regarding multi-threading, Z3 does not have a separate thread for garbage collection.